# Postgres sql query by time window

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table "meterreading" that has columns: "timestamp", "value", "meterId".  I would like to get sums of the "value" for each hour starting a specific time...  So far I have come up with this query, but it is erroring saying I need to group by timestamp.  Timestamps are just integers representing unix epoch timestamps.

```
select date_trunc('hour', to_timestamp(timestamp)) as hours, sum(value)
              from meterreading
              WHERE timestamp >= 1377993600 AND timestamp < 1409595081
              group by date_trunc('hours', to_timestamp(timestamp))
              order by date_trunc('hours', to_timestamp(timestamp)) asc
```

Comment: I guess you need a subquery that projects hours directly, on which you will then be able to group... Hint: what about gaps?

Comment: You have `'hours'` in the select and `'hour'` in the `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select date_trunc('hour', to_timestamp(timestamp)) as hours, sum(value)
from meterreading
WHERE timestamp >= 1377993600 AND timestamp < 1409595081
group by 1
order by 1
```

or use the exact same expression used in the select list

```
group by date_trunc('hour', to_timestamp(timestamp));
```

Notice `'hour'` in instead of `'hours'`. Hence the convenience of the number reference syntax in the `group by`. It is clearer and less prone to errors.